# How to find out the quadrant in which the vertex of this equation will lie

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

Given a quadratic equation $ ax^2 + bx + c = 0 $, whose roots are real and unequal; where $ a,b,c \  \in    \mathbb R^+ $ then the vertex of graph will lie in which quadrant?

Comment: I guess you mean "vertex" instead of "roots" in the title?

Comment: @imwhoiam Yes, :)

Comment: @RaviPrakash You have been around for long enough to be familiar with [How do I ask a good question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that the inequalities $a,b,c>0$ imply that the two real roots are both negative (because $ax^2 + bx + c>0$ for $x\geq 0$), and the parabola is $y=ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ is opening to the top.

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: Since $a>0$, what is the shape of the graph? (Is it U-shaped or an inverted U?)

Hint 2: Since the roots are real and unequal, the graph intersects the $x$-axis at two distinct points.

Hint 3: Show that the roots are negative.

Comment: You mean the x axis